Etale cohomology of locally constant sheaf on affine curve
In the proof of Proposition 14.12 in Milne's Lectures on 'Etale Cohomology,

Next, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally constant sheaf on $U$ with finite fibres. There exists a finite
Galois covering $\pi:U'\rightarrow U$ such that $\mathcal{F}\vert_{U'}$ is constant, and a surjective “trace map”
$\pi_*\pi^*\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$. Because $H^r(U,\pi_*\pi^*\mathcal{F})=0$ for $r\geq 2$, it follows that $H^r(U,\mathcal{F})=0$ for $r\geq 2$.

Here $U$ is nonsingular affine curve over algebraically closed field $k$, and $\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant torsion sheaf on $U$ which has no $char(k)$-torsion.
I have trouble understanding the reason why there exist such galois covering $\pi:U'\rightarrow U$. I thought that if $\{U_i\rightarrow U\}$ are etale covering where $\mathcal{F}\vert_{U_i}$ are constant sheaves, $\amalg U_i\rightarrow U$ might be candidate for $U'$, but i cannot find if this morphism is galois covering and trace is surjective or not.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

It's not clear from the way you posed the question if you also partially asking for the reason why the "trace"/ counit map should be surjective. If that's also part of the question, then see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301369/surjectivity-counit-of-pushforward-pullback-adjunction-of-an-affine-morphism In that point indeed only affinity of $\pi$ matters, so this "feature" you get for any finite (=affine + quasi finite) Galois covering for free

@user267839 I editted my question to be more clear.

@user267839 I have some question about your comment. First, the linked post says if $f$ is affine then the counit map $f^f_\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ is surjective, but i need surjectivity of $\pi_\pi^\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$.

Also, How can I make F|U′
is constant?

About how to make $F | U'$ constant: by definition of locally constant there exist a etale cover $U' \to U$ such that $F | U'$ is constant sheaf. I think you can always refine this cover to make it Galois and constance of sheaves is preserved under base change

about the other with surjectivity of trace I'm sorry I misread.

Maybe it helps to identify your map as counit from "another" adjunction (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03SH), and not the "usual" one (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122600/understanding-adjointness-of-sheaves-in-algebraic-geometry). Then, maybe you could argue using similar techniques as in the proof of Prop 2.3 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor

Another idea on surjectivity: one can check surjectivity etale locally, so you can pull back your trace map by $\pi^$ and ask about surjectivity of $\pi^\pi_\pi^ \to \pi^*F$. If you can show that this map coincides with counit from (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301369/surjectivity-counit-of-pushforward-pullback-adjunction-of-an-affine-morphism) at $\pi^*F$, you can still reduce it to that case.

Note also that in contrast to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122600/understanding-adjointness-of-sheaves-in-algebraic-geometry (where it always works) the fact that your trace map comes as a count is rather special thing where the map $\pi$ is some kind of algebro-geometric analogon of branched covering (eg for a branched covering between Riemann surfaces you have always such trace map). Cpare with Hartshorne Ex III, 6.10
